# generic CRUD views on django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create generic views for my models and I'm stuck at creating a modelform dynamically. It's there a way of creating a modelform just by having the model's name as string?

Comment: "creating a modelform dynamically"?  Why?  What possible situation leads to this?

Comment: Do you mean creating a parent model that other models can inherit from?

Comment: nope, I'm trying to get a modelform from the string of a model's name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by simply defining the class for the model form in the view's local scope and then create an instance of it directly after. You just need to make sure you receive the class of the model according to its name. Use django's `get_model` function. Simple example:

```
def my_view(request):
    model_name = "myapp.MyModel"   #make sure the app name is also provided
    from django.db.models import get_model
    model_class = get_model(*model_name.split('.'))

    class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = model_class
        # other attributes of the form

    form = MyModelForm()
    # ...
```

Comment: I was expecting a method from django so I wouldn't have to declare a class inside my view. I'll try to clean that solution and see what I can get.

Comment: Did you check the class-based generic views of Django? Esspecially the `FormView`? You still can not do it dynamically though, but you could extend it to do so with the above approach. Django does not offer you a method to do this.

Comment: I separated the class from the view inside a method and called it at the view. It looks good, thanks.